# Is there a way to read Internet Explorer in java

Tags: java, internet-explorer

lets say I'm Using Internet Explorer to look at stackoverflow.com is there a way to get the informations I'm looking at stackoverflow.com or is this impossible

Comment: You should be able to do this via COM Automation.  In theory Java can consume COM interfaces, but I've never done it.

Comment: So you mean: Start up Internet Explorer, go to stackoverflow.com, execute a java file, and have the java file retrieve the String `stackoverflow.com` somehow?

Comment: Well you could do that, if you are really interested the software equivalent of a Rube Goldberg machine. Or ... you could use one of the many HTTP client libraries to just read all the HTML from the page directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/). It is a browser automation framework that allows you to control a browser (such as Internet Explorer) through code in Java, .NET, Ruby, or Python.

**Edit**: If you're wondering if it's possible for an external Java application to know that the user happens to have IE open and is looking at a certain website, I can't help you there. That isn't to say it isn't possible; I just don't know whether it is or not.